# Is there a way to run AIR application with admin privileges on Windows 7 right after installation?

Tags: windows, air, admin

I have an AIR application. It works on Windows XP, but on Windows 7 it only works if I give it admin privileges. I don't mind doing that, but how do I setup it so that once I run application after install - it would ask for admin privileges itself?

Answer (score -2):

Try enabling the "extendedDesktop" profile in the app descriptor file.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html

Comment: Thank you, but we already have that enabled - it doesn't start application with admin permissions.

Comment: Looking for the same solution, answepr provided @lukevanin is incorrect, or please ellaborate more.